# unable to recursively download images

Tags: android, download

Hi i am trying to recursively download the images but i am unable to. 
It only downloads the first image! does any one know why?

this is my code to download, I did a log to check if there are items in my list and yes, there are 20:

```
Log.d("imageList.size",String.valueOf(imageList.size()));
try
        {
            for (int i=0; i<=imageList.size(); i++)
            {
            String image= imageList.get(i);
            Log.d("imageList.get(0)",image);
            String filename = String.valueOf(image.hashCode());
            Log.v("TAG FILE :", filename);

            File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);

        // Is the bitmap in our cache?
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getPath());
        if (bitmap != null)
            return bitmap;

        else {
            // Nope, have to download it
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(image)
                        .openConnection().getInputStream());
                // save bitmap to cache for later
                writeFile(bitmap, f);
                return bitmap;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("FILE NOT FOUND", "FILE NOT FOUND");
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            return null;
```

Comment: check the list, to ensure you have as many elements as you claim.

Comment: yea, i have checked the array list. it does consist of items

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with your **for** loop, it is exiting on the first iteration of the loop, check your braces and ensure that you have the braces setup the way you intend it and the logic **makes sense**. You should **NOT** return until your for loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

Line: 25 in your code, do not return before the loop ends.